# Getting a string value from the strings.xml resource file and set it in an interface class

Tags: android, string, interface

My code

```
String username = "@string/default_username";
```

default_username is the key name in String file.

the problem is when i try to call `username` in retrofit, it cant get the value from String file and just print `@string/default_username` instead of getting the value inside.

Is it possible to get key value and set it in interface class?

Comment: the reason im doing it this way, that im using productFlavour

Comment: Why don't you pass a context to your interface and get the string? Could you please share code of your interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access a string on the strings.xml file, you need to get it through `getString(R.string. default_username);`

In your case,

`String username = getString(R.string. default_username);`